# How to enable CORS in Sails.js on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, cors, openshift, sails.js

I'm trying to enable CORS in SailsJS v0.9.15...
It doesn't help if i set "allRoutes: true" in cors.js, i'm still getting CORS related errors. Why is this not working? According to this, it should be enough... https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/todo/config.cors.md

Error in Firefox: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at www.domain.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Error in Chrome: "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'null'. Origin 'www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Is this a bug?

Sails.js (REST api) is hosted on Openshift, could that be a problem?

Thanks for help...

Comment: Are the two parts of your application (the application, and the API) hosted on different services or different domains?

Comment: Yes, API is hosted on Openshift PaaS, client application is a single page backbone application at this time (in future it will be a mobile phonegap application).

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be an issue with OpenShift in general filtering out the CORS headers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978344/openshift-access-control-allow-origin-set-by-server-for-get-request-disappears.  Hopefully someone from OpenShift will answer that.

Comment: I'm using sails rc8 on my localhost and I am still getting this error on chrome. I tried to modify config/cors.js allRoutes and set it to true, but then I get another error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.106:1337/session/mobileCheckAuth?_dc=1405003092187. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Same happens when hosting on Heroku, but this is less important to me.

Any idea? I need this for testing from my Chrome browser.

Comment: @user2867106, take a look at the [documentation](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.cors.html), specifically the `headers` setting...

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this official, there is an [open issue about CORS headers being filtered out by OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978344/openshift-access-control-allow-origin-set-by-server-for-get-request-disappears).  CORS should work fine in Sails for deployments that don't block those headers.  Documentation for CORS in Sails is [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors) and [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-security).