# Hello, I need to know how to enable CORS in a RAILS REST app at OpenShift for Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, .htaccess

I have a little script that uses Angular to list some records from a Rails API REST hosted in OpenShift, my public/.htaccess looks like this:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"

PassengerFriendlyErrorPages off
```

My Html/Angular looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Test Angular from Shared Hosting to OpenShift RAILS API REST</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MyApp">
      <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img alt="100%x200" data-src="holder.js/100%x200" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-holder-rendered="true">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{post.name}}</h3>
                    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
                    <p><a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular-resource.js"></script>



      <script>
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngResource']);

        app.factory("Post", function($resource) {
          return $resource("http://vr-20puntos.rhcloud.com/tables.json");
        });
        app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, Post) {
          Post.query(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
          });
        });

      </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't know what happen, I'm using the Free Plan just for testing

Comment: Have you checked the [CORS guide](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html). Generally I'd use `"*"` instead of `"*.*"`

Comment: I used * too ut nothing happens, this is the message: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://vr-20puntos.rhcloud.com/tables.json. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Comment: Itried with: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version'
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age '1728000'

Comment: Have you tried a `JSONP` instead of `JSON`? The [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) **Edit** The `tables.json` looks like in JSONP format. Have you analysed the response header from OpenShift?

Comment: How can I use JSonP with Angular?

Comment: I already find out how to use JSonP with Angular, but I have no response

Comment: Found this [issue with OpenShift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978344/openshift-access-control-allow-origin-set-by-server-for-get-request-disappears). Angular's [$http.jsonp doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: I cannot belive that OpenShift have this kind of CORS issues

Comment: Next, fix the `tables.json` mine-type, `Refused to execute script from 'http://vr-20puntos.rhcloud.com/tables.json?callback=jQuery190006028701923787594_1437600826432&_=1437600826433' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled`

Comment: tables.json is a Rails API REST, I'll fid out how to configure this on Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in `comments` section but it has gotten too long. Here's my take on this issue:

1. Working [demo](http://app-alkhoo.rhcloud.com/json.html) from OpenShift that uses jQuery with callback, images from flickr site.
2. OpenShift **DOES NOT** allow CORS enabled in its headers (ya, it is 2015! Tried a few configuration but no go)
3. Modify your `tables.json` code to follow the output of `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?`, can't go wrong with the big boys.

Also look into the console and check the 'response headers' since that will help you debug the CORS issue. Good luck

Comment: Thank you I'll try this out